# How To Prevent Processes From Starting?

Tags: windows, security, winapi

I'm toying around with a very simplistic sort of process-monitor.  Currently, it gets a list of the running processes and attempts to kill any process that is not white-listed.

What I'm looking for is a way to prevent a process from starting that isn't on the white-list.  If that's possible.  My knowledge level in this area is pretty non-existent and my Google-fu only returns websites discussing Process.Start() :(

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Learn about windwows hooks. Try to hook CreateProcess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See ['Hooking the native API and controlling process creation on a system-wide basis'](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/soviet_protector.aspx) for an example. Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293624/monitor-process-start-in-the-system)