# Hook dll into exe

Tags: c#, dll, exe

I have my C# dll file, and I want to hook this dll into an exe file ( exe is not mine and C++ )

for example i have code in my dll like

```
MessageBox.Show("Active");
```

and I want to show this message after double click exe ,

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Comment: A C# program requires a lot of runtime support.  You don't just have to inject your C# DLL, you also have to inject the CLR and the jitter.  There's no support for that builtin whatsoever, the process has to co-operate.  It won't.

Comment: what if i call C# code in C++ dll ? Is that fix my problem ?

Comment: Yes, if you make a small native DLL that wraps the C# then you are good. Presumably you imagine adding something to the PE import table to get your DLL into the process?

Comment: yes with PE import table DLL into the process , I don't have knowladge with C++, can i find any C++ project wraps the C# ?

Answer (score 1):

On a basic level, what you are asking is not straightforward - you can't easily get the .exe to run your code if you have no way of editing and recompiling the .exe.

However, if you only want to be able to find out when the process starts, you could check out [Monitor process start in the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293624/monitor-process-start-in-the-system).

Comment: Not so. You can install a global hook for example. Or you can detect process startup and inject with `CreateRemoteThread`.

Comment: Edited for clarity. My answer does have a link to hooking techniques, but a CreateRemoteThread example would be interesting!

Comment: C++ dll do this easyly with tools like LordPE , why  not C# ?
other i will try to make C# code under C++ Dll, there is look only way