# how to hook a process before its execution using vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, hook, event-hooking

Could anybody tell me how to hook a process before or just at its execution. I want to get all the information of process before starting and check if it is authorized by user or not.

Comment: what is it for, like an antiviurs program?

Comment: may be something like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitor process start in the system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293624/monitor-process-start-in-the-system)